# Альтернатива продуктам JetBrains

Tags: jetbrains, datagrip

Говорят, что JetBrains хочет нас покинуть...

Я использовал продукт [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/ru-ru/datagrip/) (работа с БД) от этой кампании. У меня лицензия кончается в апреле, поэтому начинаю подумывать о другом продукте.

Есть какой аналог? Кто что посоветует?

Comment: Добавьте, если не сложно, в вопрос краткое описание - а какой у этого продукта функционал вообще.

Comment: @CrazyElf, добавил + ссылку на продукт

Comment: До 1 октября минимум ваша подписка продлится автоматически.

Comment: @moscas, у меня лицензия от **Stepik** - уже кончалась (в указанный срок), потом я решал задания и мне давали новую. Поэтому из опыта уже предполагаю, что она не продлится и закончится в указанный день

Comment: Бесплатные лицензии будут предоставляться на тех же условиях, что и раньше.